# Find network transfer size for Java RMI Application

Tags: networking, bandwidth

We've developed a client/server solution using Java RMI. We wish to know the amount of data being transfer over the wire from server to client so we can judge bandwidth requirements.

I've created a capture of the traffic using wireshark, however is there a way to find the total size of all the packets?

If wireshark isn't the best solution, can someone please suggest a better application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, in Wireshark just go to statistics (top menu bar) and choose 'conversations'.  There go to the IPv4 list (showing you host to host conversation stats, find your server<->client conversation) and look at the 'Bytes' size... it'll even show you client>server and server>client packets/bytes.

Answer (score 0):

First, apply the needed filter to your captured packets so that you can see only the relevant packets.

Then, go to "Statistics" -> "Summary". You can find useful information. I think you want the "Bytes" value.